# API Platform: No such file or directory

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I'm working my way through the API Platform tutorial called "Creating your First API with API Platform, in 5 Minutes." When I run this command:

docker-compose exec app bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

I get these errors:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
>   An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

The entities appeared to have generated correctly when I ran:

docker-compose exec app bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Command `docker-compose exec app bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle` will create a entity file. It will not create any database table only a file in your project.

The problem probably is in your docker configuration or with database configuration in docker image/container (check comment in your question). Maybe you should add database definition to you `docker-compose.yml` file

Check this [Symfony Docker](https://github.com/maxpou/docker-symfony). It includes a lot of unnecessary services but it is a good start point.

Comment: I tried changing the MySQL settings (i.e. MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD) in the docker-compose.yml file, but that didn't work. Everything appears to be correct in the parameters.yml file. The "foo" API worked when I first installed API Platform. The install created the api_platform database correctly.once I had the parameters.yml values correct, so I know that it was able to connect to the DB at that time. I'm still stumped! Please help!

Comment: Maybe go to the beginning. Try run: **docker-compose exec app bin/console doctrine:database:create --force** 
and then **docker-compose exec app bin/console doctrine:schema:create**

Comment: Thanks @bliszka! That didn't work, but I really appreciate the suggestion! I'm desperate for ideas at this point. :-)